# how to implement Z coefficients in C?

Tags: c, matlab, filter, signal-processing

I have obtained some Z coefficients in MatLAB. Now I need to implement the filter in C.
How do I do this?
The coefficients in Z domain:

num = [0.2557   -0.5115   -0.2557    1.0230   -0.2557   -0.5115    0.2557];

den = [1.0000   -4.0196    6.1894   -4.4532    1.4208   -0.1418    0.0044];

Any help is appreciated.

(I tried googling, but didn't find anything clear and easy to understand.)

Comment: [Matlab Coder](http://www.mathworks.fr/products/matlab-coder/) can help you to generate the C code directly.

Comment: If you could switch to C++ this might help: https://ccrma.stanford.edu/software/stk - a tutorial on using it's filters can be found here: https://ccrma.stanford.edu/software/stk/filtering.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that the main issue is translating from Z domain to time.

Y(z) = H(z)*X(z)

H(z) = B(z)/A(z) = Y(z)/X(z)

B(z)*X(z) = A(z)*Y(z)

Then from the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/butter.html):

B(z) = b(1)*z^-n + ... + b(n+1)
A(z) = z^-n + ... + a(n+1)

Converting to time domain:

b(1)*x(t) + b(2)*x(t-1) + ... + b(n+1)*x(t-n) = a(1)y(t) + ... + a(n+1)*y(t-n)

Then 'solving' for y(t), given that a(1) is 1:

y(t) = b(1)*x(t) + b(2)*x(t-1) + ... + b(n+1)*x(t-n) - a(2)*y(t-1) ... - a(n+1)*y(t-n)

where n = 7.  So, say you have to arrays in which you store the last 6 values of the input x and the filter output y:

```
/* Warning Warning Warning: 
   This has not been tested,
   for illustration purposes only */
double filter_data(double x)
{
  static double x_prev[6] = {0};
  static double y_prev[6] = {0};
  /* x is newest input value */
  double y;  /* output to be calculated */
  int ii;

  /* let's just keep it really simple for now, you can get more sophisticated later */
  y = 0.2557*x[0] + -0.5115*x_prev[0] + -0.2557*x_prev[1] + 1.0230*x_prev[2] + 
      -0.2557*x_prev[3] + -0.5115*x_prev[4] + 0.2557*x_prev[5] - -4.0196*y_prev[0] - 
      6.1894*y_prev[1] - -4.4532*y_prev[2] - 1.4208*y_prev[3] - -0.1418*y_prev[4] - 
      0.0044*y_prev[5];

  /* really really wasteful, but simple shift of previous values */
  for(ii=5;ii>0;ii--)
  {
    y_prev[ii] = y_prev[ii-1]
    x_prev[ii] = x_prev[ii-1]
  }
  y_prev[0] = y;
  x_prev[0] = x;
  return y;
}
```

It's not great, but I think that ought to get you going.  Let me know if something isn't clear!

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you very much. But I dont quite understand why you want to shift the vales. The input data I have is from a microphone and stored in a buffer. Cant I loop through the buffer to calculate the current output value instead of shifting the value in the buffer?

Comment: @user1675128, the value shifting is to make sure every time you call the function, you have a coherent data set.  If you have a buffer of data you could easily refractory the code to account for that.  I was only trying to show a possible solution.